# cURLFTPFS only lists the mounted directory. Reading a file is forbidden, writing a file is forbidden, creating new files is forbidden

Tags: curl, ftp, fuse, curlftpfs

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask this question, but when searching for `curlftpfs` in all sites on StackExchange, the majority of the returned results, lead to StackOverflow.

So, I have a server running Pure-FTPd with a virtual user named `http`, who is running under the system user `www-data` (Apache's user) and it's home folder is `/var/www/`. The Pure-FTPd is configured properly and the `www-data` user has all privileges over `/var/www/` needed for reading, writing and executing. Everything works as expected when an http request is made against port 80 (ensuring proper execution), and reading, writing and creating new files and directories with FileZilla (remotely).

The problem comes when I try to mount the remote directory with `curlftpfs` in a local directory (inside my user's home folder). The command I'm using is as follows:

```
curlftpfs ftp://http:passw0rd@192.168.0.100 ~/ftp
```

(Note: the `http` in `ftp://http:passw0rd...` is the username I'm using to connect and it works fine, I'm pretty sure the problem is not related to this.)

The content of the remote `/var/www/` is listed properly, I can browse inside the subdirectories, but I cannot read a file, write into a file or create a new file or folder. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to specifically set the allow_other flag.  Try

```
curlftpfs 192.168.0.100 ~/ftp -o allow_other,user=http:password
```

Comment: Same thing, not allowed to create new files, nor reading the existing ones. Yet, folder listing works.